# SQL to retrieve first sentence from a block of text

Tags: sql, sql-server, text, substring

I have the following SQL for SQL server:

```
declare @summary1 as nvarchar(max)
declare @summary2 as nvarchar(max)

set @summary1='this is some long text. this is the rest of the text'
set @summary2='some text with no full stops'

select substring(@summary1, 1,CHARINDEX('.', @summary1)) as sentence
select substring(@summary2, 1,CHARINDEX('.', @summary2)) as sentence
```

I want to be able to get the first sentence from "summary" and if there is no full stop return all the text. The example for @summary1 works fine but clearly with no full stop in the text nothing is returned.

Anyone have any bright ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `CASE`*expression*:

```
SELECT 
CASE CHARINDEX('.', @summary1)  -- determine if the sentence contains a full stop
    WHEN 0 THEN @summary1       -- if not return the whole sentence
    ELSE SUBSTRING(@summary1, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @summary1))  -- else first part
END AS sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
select substring(@summary1, 1,CHARINDEX('.', @summary1)) as sentence
select substring(@summary2, 1,CHARINDEX('.', @summary2+'.')) as sentence
```

This will add a stop to the end of the line, even if it's there. You could set up if / else statements to determine if there is already a dot at the end, and append one accordingly.

`@summary2` returns `some text with no full stops`